# Unable to console log in real time chat application js files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I am building a real-time chat application using Node.js and socket.io.

I have built two js files - index.js for handling socket connection server requests and client.js for the client-side code. When I include console.log, I cannot get the output in the command line.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--connects server and client-->
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/client.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>NiChat App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav>
        <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Log">
    </nav>

    <!--Container for the chat app-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="message" id="m-left">Palpatine: Did you ever hear the tragedy of Darth Plagueis the wise?</div>
        <div class="message" id="m-right">Anakin: No.</div>
    </div>

    <!--Send box-->
    <div class="send">
        <form id="send-container" action="#">
            <input type="text" name="msgInp" id="msgInp">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
//file which will host the socket io 

const io = require("socket.io")(8000)

const users = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => { //io.on listens to several socket connections
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('new-user-joined', Name => { //accepts an event 'new-user-joined' 
        console.log('New user', Name)
        users[socket.id] = Name;
        socket.broadcast.emit('user-joined', Name)
    });
    socket.on('send', message => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('receive', { message: message, name: users[socket.id] })
    });
})
```

**client.js**

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
```

```
const form = document.getElementById('send-container');const msgInp = document.getElementById('msgInp');const msgContainer = document.querySelector(".container")const Name = prompt("Enter your name to join");socket.emit('new-user-joined', Name)
```

The client.js file is within the **js** folder.

The index.js is within the **node_modules** folder.

[image]

Please help me out.

I tried putting console.log at different places of both the js files but am unable to produce an output.

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't be able to use console.log to output data in realtime, since it is not a real-time logging system. You can, however, use other logging libraries to output real-time data, such as Winston or Bunyan.

Comment: @Talha What do you mean by "`console.log` not being real-time"?

Comment: Does your clientside script work? Are you getting any errors in the browser devtools?

Comment: @Bergi Console.log is a logging system that outputs data to the console. It is not a real-time system, meaning that it does not output data as it is received. This means that if you are trying to log real-time data, such as data from a socket connection, you won't be able to use console.log to do this, as it will only output data after the connection is closed. To output real-time data, you need to use a logging library that is specifically designed for real-time logging. Examples of such libraries include Winston and Bunyan.

Comment: By "*Unable to console log*", do you mean that your code works without the `console.log` and you cannot get the logging to work, or that your code doesn't work at all and you don't know why the event handlers are not running while you expected them to be executed?

Comment: @Talha "*it will only output data after the connection is closed*" - uh, no? What makes you think that? Are we talking about the same [`console.log`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consolelogdata-args)?

Comment: There is a prompt in the client.js. When I enter a data in the prompt, it is stored in the const name and I am emitting it to the index.js socket and there I am providing the output in the console.log But the output is not showing

Comment: @NisargKudgunti So, does the connection work at all? Do you see the expected request/messages in the network panel of your browser devtools?

Comment: @Bergi Sir, I am getting the socket.io connection as blocked

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=ONLuTVn. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

Answer (score 0):

This answer provided the solution to my question.
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48593746/16131596)

Adding this `{ transports: ['websocket'] }` inside the io makes the problem go away.